# QML: internal/external CSS properties

Tags: css, qt, qml

I have some QML Text (RichText) items with multiple CSS-styled html elements  via inline 'style' attribute inside each tag (e.g `<code style=\"background-color:black; text-indent: 10px\"></code>`). Wondering is there way to somehow apply CSS properties globally?

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Comment: I don't think, that you can specify global CSS styles with the Rich Text Engine.

Comment: something like using the `<style>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about external styling (separate CSS file), but internal styling (`<style></style>`) works within QML item